# how to update one db when another db insert a record?

Tags: python, django

I use django admin site,there are two tables, one is `Category` which has a `totalitems` column storing total number articles of this category ,the other is `Article`,`Article` has a foreign key reference `Category`,when i create a new article in admin site,then an update should increment the `Category totalitems`,i failed in this way:

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,help_text='primary key',auto_created=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text='category name')
    description = models.TextField(default='',help_text='category description')
    coverimg = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',help_text='category front cover image')
    covercolor = models.CharField(max_length=7,default='#ffffff',help_text='color for each category background')
    totalitems = models.IntegerField(default=0,help_text='total items for each category')
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modifytime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    categories = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article_category'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#blog article models
class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (0,'on'),
        (1,'off')
    )
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,help_text='primary key',auto_created=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='articles', help_text='foreigner key reference Category')
    #author = models.ForeignKey(myadmin.User, help_text='foreigner key reference myadmin User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='article title')
    description = models.TextField(help_text='article brief description')
    content = models.TextField(help_text='article content')
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0,help_text='like numbers')
    secretcode = models.CharField(max_length=512,help_text='who has the code can scan')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS,help_text='status of the article')
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,help_text='time that first created')
    modifytime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,help_text='time when modified')

    articles = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            Category.categories.filter(articles=Article).update(totalitems = F('totalitems')+1)
        super(Article,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

although the sql operation succeed,but the column totalitems not updated,where i was doing wrong? and where is the best place to automatically updated affected models,in Model or in django AdminSite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing an answer that offers an alternative approach as requested in the question comments.

Instead of persisting a 'calculated field', calculate it when needed at runtime via a total_items() function on the Category class.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,help_text='primary key',auto_created=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text='category name')
    description = models.TextField(default='',help_text='category description')
    coverimg = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',help_text='category front cover image')
    covercolor = models.CharField(max_length=7,default='#ffffff',help_text='color for each category background')
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modifytime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    categories = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article_category'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def total_items(self):
        return Articles.objects.filter(category=self).count()
```

Comment: Thanks,but where is my **totalitems** column?

Comment: It's removed and that's my point. You don't want to persist it, you want to calculate when needed at runtime.

Comment: does it perform better than former?

Comment: In your specific case (where I assume you'll read/write Articles more frequently than Categories) this will require more database reads (although it does save the extra write when creating an Article). However there is trade off. It avoids the need for more code to handle cases where an Article is deleted or an Article changes category (you would need to decrement the totalitems field).

Comment: No problem - if you think this is a better explanation would you mind re-assigning the answer?

Comment: i have another question,please!! [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714419/how-to-get-extra-column-in-relational-model-in-django-rest-framework-serializer

Answer (score 2):

Change the filter expression:

```
Category.categories.filter(pk=self.category.pk).update(
                                            totalitems = F('totalitems') + 1)
```

But anyway you will have wrong `totalitems` count in case of deletion of `Article`.  Changing the article's category will lead to invalid total count too.

Comment: Thanks,is there an alternative?

Comment: Use the `category.articles.count()` which is always valid.  If you output categories in a list then `prefetch_related()` will solve performance problems (if you will get any).

Comment: This approach is known as a 'calculated field' and has some drawbacks. The typical alternative is to make the calculation in a function on the Category class.

Comment: @dwightgunning ,can you both show some detailed codes samples please?i am new to django,Thanks.