# How to get an extra column in relational model in Django-rest-framework serializer?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have `Category` and `Article` model,`Article` has a foreign key reference `Category`,in my `serializer` i can get the name column in Category model because of the _`_str__` method,but how can i get other columns in `Category` model

models.py:

```
# blog category models
class Category(models.Model):
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,help_text='primary key',auto_created=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text='category name')
    description = models.TextField(default='',help_text='category description')
    coverimg = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',help_text='category front cover image')
    covercolor = models.CharField(max_length=7,default='#ffffff',help_text='color for each category background')
    totalitems = models.IntegerField(default=0,help_text='total items for each category')
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modifytime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    categories = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article_category'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#blog article models
class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (0,'on'),
        (1,'off')
    )
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,help_text='primary key',auto_created=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='articles', help_text='foreigner key reference Category')
    #author = models.ForeignKey(myadmin.User, help_text='foreigner key reference myadmin User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='article title')
    description = models.TextField(help_text='article brief description')
    content = models.TextField(help_text='article content')
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0,help_text='like numbers')
    secretcode = models.CharField(max_length=512,help_text='who has the code can scan')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS,help_text='status of the article')
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,help_text='time that first created')
    modifytime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,help_text='time when modified')

    articles = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            Category.categories.filter(pk=self.category.pk).update(totalitems = F('totalitems')+1)
        super(Article,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializers.py:

```
#   Article catalog
class ArticleCatalogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    articletags = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    covercolor = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'category', 'articletags', 'description', 'like', 'createtime', 'covercolor')
```

covercolor = serializers.StringRelatedField()  would cause an error:`Article' object has no attribute 'covercolor`  and i changed to this :

**changed serializers.py:**

```
#   category serializer for ArticleCatalogSerializer for nested relationship
class CategoryNestedRelationshipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('covercolor',)

#   Article catalog
class ArticleCatalogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    articletags = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    covercolor = CategoryNestedRelationshipSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        ields = ('id', 'title', 'category', 'articletags', 'description', 'like', 'createtime', 'covercolor')
```

**got an error:**

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `covercolor` on serializer `ArticleCatalogSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Article` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Article' object has no attribute 'covercolor'.
```

how to implement this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your edit , Change your ArticleCatalogSerializer to

```
class ArticleCatalogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategoryNestedRelationshipSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

you will get output in this format

```
{
"id": 1,
"category": {
"covercolor": "#ffffff"
},
"title": "sa",
"description": "bhjghj",
"content": "sda",
"like": 0,
"secretcode": "77",
"status": 0,
"createtime": "2015-04-18T07:52:57.230110Z",
"modifytime": "2015-04-18T07:52:57.230135Z"
}
```

If you want any other column of category , you can include in your category serializer like this

```
class CategoryNestedRelationshipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('covercolor','name','description')
```

Comment: this worked perfectly.In an model,if you reference any column related to the relation model,the foreign key should be the entrance,in the former case,i just reference category foreign key which returns its name,just only one column,if there is much columns,you should query them on relation model,and make it a nest relationship and insert into Article,which is an array.am i thinking right?

Comment: Saved my day... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The StringRelatedField will emit the string representation of the related field.

To keep the 'flat' format you'll need to write a [custom](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) Field.

Alternatively if you want to include some reference to the Category, you'd want a PrimaryKeyRelatedField or [nest](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) the related model.

Comment: i changed to **covercolor = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)**  still not work~

Comment: Ahh, well if you're serializing an Article model then that'll be because covercolor attribute (it's on the related Category). To keep the 'flat' format you'll need to write a custom Field.

Comment: i have edited my question,take a look,where i was wrong?